# Call to undefined method ExampleTest::assertStatus()

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, lumen

I'm using Lumen for api building and also want to write unit test cases for that. But the problem I'm facing is not a single assert method is working. Like `assertStatus()`, `assertNotFound()`, `assertJson()`, etc. All of them giving error as **Call to undefined method ExampleTest::assertMethod()**. Below is my ExampleTest file.

```
<?php

use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->get('/');

        $this->assertEquals(
            $this->app->version(), $this->response->getContent()
        );
    }

    /** @test */
    public function testExample2()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        //getting error here
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

I'm wring test cases for the first time in Lumen. Plese guide me through this process.

Comment: Can you add `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` at the top?

Comment: It says Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase' not found after adding it to top.

Comment: The **TestCase.php** file is already there in the same directory. So I think there is no need to include it through use.

Comment: Can you check what the `TestCase` class is extending from ? To make  this work `TestCase` should extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` and `$response` then has to be `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse`

Comment: Sure. It is extending from this class below. 

`<?php

abstract class TestCase extends Laravel\Lumen\Testing\TestCase
{
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Laravel\Lumen\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        return require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    }
}`

Comment: If its Limen then you need to do `$this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());` [documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.7/testing)

Comment: Yes. I'm using Lumen. It worked this way 

`public function testExample2()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');
 
        $this->assertEquals(200, $this->response->status());
    }` Thanks.

Comment: Sure,  Let me post it as an answer with little more explanation for anyone coming in future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some of  the ways to assert are different if you are using Lumen's `Laravel\Lumen\Testing\TestCase`  vs Laravel's default `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`.

If you want to assertStatus for `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`:

```
public function testHomePage()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

The same for `Laravel\Lumen\Testing\TestCase` :

```
public function testHomePage()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $this->response->status());
    }
```

[Laravel Testing Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/testing) and [Lumen Testing Documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.7/testing)

Comment: in lumen `9.0.2` you can use `$response->assertResponseStatus(200)`. If you just want assert you response status

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Test Suit more like the Laravel, you can use this package:
https://packagist.org/packages/albertcht/lumen-testing

Then you can use the asserts like the Laravel